# How can I disable cache memory in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Is there any option to turn off cache memory in Internet explorer 9.
the reason why I need to bug fix on browser compatibility. whenever testing pages I need to clear cache. It seems to be bit time wasting for me

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to do this, unfortunately. Refer to this for some quick tips, though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Internet_Explorer

Comment: Indeed, so does Safari, as well as Chrome. However, the question was about IE9, no? ;)

Comment: @DanielNeri of course, for IE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link 
-->  http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/2317-Internet-Explorer-9-Managing-Cookies-and-Cache-

basicly  its just:

- hit f12
- click cache
- select something like 'always refresh from server' (mine is in different language)